# EclipseLink JPA - location of persistence.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink, persistence.xml

I am using JPA for a java class and having trouble putting the persistence XML file where it should be.

The IDE i am using is Eclipse Helios. Eclipselink jar files are downloaded and added to my JRE  System Library and all. I wrote up the persistence.xml with the  tag after getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named customers
```

Provider tag:

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

The program still doesn't run so i am wondering where should I place persistence.xml (i.e src/main/resources, or lib/META-INF... etc )

Comment: I find it unexpected that it's in META-INF rather than WEB-INF when you consider the xml file for spring beans is in WEB-INF.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`persistence.xml` should be put inside an directory called `META-INF` under the root of the classpath .

**Right click your project in eclipse ==> Properties ==> Java Build Path** . Suppose you configure one of the  build paths to be  `/src/main/resources` , then you should put the `persistence.xml` at `/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

Comment: how can i set a customized path for persistence.xml ?

Comment: @Lucky - I'm sure you've found the answer now but just in case anyone else is wondering: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24861395/714112

Answer (score 1):

### JPA persistence XML file location

Traditionally, the persistence.xml is located in a `META-INF` folder that needs to reside in the root of the Java classpath. If you’re using Maven, you can store it in the `resources` folder, like this:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
```