# application-context Spring configuration file not found

Tags: java, spring, soap, cxf

I'd like to create a simple soap webservice with `Spring` and `CXF`. But my `application-context.xml` configuration file is not found:

webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

webapp/WEB-INF/application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Result:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 21 more
```

Why? What am I missing here?

Comment: add webapp to classpath

Comment: `WEB-INF` isn't on your classpath. Use `/WEB-INF/application-context.xml` instead. No prefix.

Comment: One thing I found is that there is a delay in unpacking the zip file, and it tries to start up before the required file is there. If I wait another few minutes it magically starts up. I'm using CXF too. Maybe that adds an unexpected delay somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a working application in which I've set:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: You could have left it out, as that is the default location.